# How to switch to discrete graphics ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have an Integrated Intel graphics and AMD Radeon R5 M230 graphics card. and I want to switch to AMD whenever I want to.

I ran the lspci command for you to see.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
```

[Additional drivers tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSv8M.png)

Comment: If you want to switch between graphics cards and see the same windows displayed I don't know how to do that.  However, if you don't mind having two instances of X running, each having a separate set of windows (like having 2 workspaces) that should be feasible and you could switch between them with Ctl-Alt-Fn keystrokes.  See [http://superuser.com/questions/117239/how-can-i-get-multiple-video-cards-to-work-on-linux] for a good place to start.  You will need 2 xorg.conf files and to start 2 instances of X, each using its own file.  Of course, there may be a smarter solution...

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to have this screen snapshot handy from a question I posted a couple hours ago:

[image]

From your launcher select **System Settings** then **Software & Updates** and then pick **Additional Drivers** tab.

On my screen the manufacturer shows as "NVIDIA" but on yours it will show "AMD". If you have multiple choices and don't know which to pick you can print your screen and `Edit` your question to show that image.

Comment: edited with screenshot of my Additional drivers above.

Comment: @Naster In that case you need to read this Q&A: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Comment: But isn't that for ubuntu 14?  I've read on some sites that fglrx is not work in ubuntu 16

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll have to research the subject further.

Comment: This will not work. `fglrx` doesn't work on 16.04 or 14.04.5. Read my Q&A, which I linked in the comments of the question.

Comment: @Zacharee1 OK. Is there anything that will work for Naster?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix My Q&A has options. That's why I marked it as a dupe.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Hello brother, Thanks for the response, Im trying to implement the OIBAF drivers method.  Is there a tutorial how to set it up? Coz It's abit confusing for me

Comment: @Naster I would assume you just add the PPA and install, but I haven't tried.